# UNUserNotificationCenter.add not finishing in iOS Share Extension

Tags: ios, unusernotificationcenter, ios8-share-extension

My iOS app has a share-extension where users can also upload Attachments.
As those can be large, the upload is done using an `URLSession` with `URLSessionConfiguration.background`. After the upload is done, I'd like to show the user some kind of success-ui and chose a Notification for that purpose. So now in my completion block I am doing something like that:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.body = "Success"

let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.add(request)
print("This line is never called")
```

and as you can see in my sample code here, the app is stuck ad `center.add(request)`. This method is just never completing?!? When calling it, I am on the main-thread, but also tried on other threads... always the same result

Does anybody have an idea why?